# Intellij "Unable to open debugger port" Java SBT project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been running tests all afternoon and suddenly when I tried to debug a test, the below error appeared. I've looked at the runner at the bottom to see if any tests are running and there aren't, I can't even click on the debug tag. Does anyone know why this would suddenly occur?

I am using the latest version of Intellij to run a java test in an SBT project.

> Error running TestName:
>   Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:51795): java.net.BindException "Address already in use"